# When adding a basic object I can't find the option to display vertices

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, vertices

I'm encountering an issue when I add a basic object like a circle or cylinder to my scene, I can't seem to find the option to display the vertices. This is hindering my ability to edit and work with the object effectively.

I've attached a screenshot of the problem for reference:
[image]

I've tried searching through various settings and preferences, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the vertices visible. Could someone assist me on how to enable vertex display.

Comment: hello, this is a curve object, not a mesh object, maybe what you want is a Mesh > Circle instead?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to create a mesh object, but what you show is a curve object, not a mesh object, to create a mesh object like for example a circle: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Circle*:

[image]